# Training Data set for Name entity recognition using StanfordNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have used OpenNLP to create an model. But now i am looking into StanfordNLP which uses Condition Random Field. I want to know how to train a data for NER using stanfordNLP.
For OpenNLp we use START and END tag but i do no how to train using StanfordNLP. please give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#b

That should explain what you need to know to get started. There are then many options mainly only documented in the code.